# My div tags aren't lining up properly

Tags: css, html

Can't figure out what's going on, I know it's div related but can't quite figure out where I'm going wrong. Can someone have a quick look and tell me where I'm goofed, or better yet, how to fix it?

It's the blue line at the bottom of the page. I've tried everything I know (which isn't much anymore). Thanks for any advice!

Website:
http://www.cityplaceselfstorage.com

-Jason

Answer (score 1):

Change the height property on `#templatemo_middle` to auto. Currently the height is specified at 347px.

Answer (score 0):

Update following rule:

```
#templatemo_middle {
    background: url("images/templatemo_content.jpg") no-repeat scroll left bottom transparent;
    clear: both;
    color: #F6F6F6;
    height: 305px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    width: 960px;
}
```

changing height auto will misplace the world map image of background of this div.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do few arrangement of css code and add extra div

**First Step:**
Change CSS of .templatemo_middle to following

```
.templatemo_middle{
    clear: both;
    width: 960px;
    height: auto;
    color: #f6f6f6;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
/** remove background image from here **/
}

/**add new class which will be used for new div */
.new_class{
     background: url(/images/templatemo_content.jpg) no-repeat scroll left top transparent;
}
```

**Second Step:**
Content Within .v_divider should be enclosed to another div and the background can be assigned

```
<div class="col_w540 float_l v_divider">
    <div class='new_class'>
        ....here goes content....



      .....
    </div><!-- end the new div -->
</div><!-- end of div.v_divider -->
```

Save it and run